# OpenWRT пропал инет после прошивки

Tags: openwrt, маршрутизатор, прошивка, tp-link

У меня роутер TP-Link TL-WR740N v5. Обновил до последней версии. Потом установил прошивку openwrt по инструкции https://habrahabr.ru/post/186760/. 5-ую версию загрузил с офф. сайта. Особенных настроек не требовал провайдер. Даже в заводском режиме инет работал. Но после прошивки инет пропал. Точнее цвет горит, но инета нету. Заходил через ssh проверил команду wget. Безуспешно. Ещё и нету веб интерфейса. uhttpd вообще нету. Установит не получается так как инета нету в ssh. 
Не знаю что делать дальше.
ip динамичный.
Интернет оптоволоконный.

ifconfig:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ifconfig
br-lan    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:E3:27:86:36:ED
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::62e3:27ff:fe86:36ed/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fd62:515a:4b82::1/60 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19017 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13892 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1715197 (1.6 MiB)  TX bytes:1244335 (1.1 MiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:E3:27:86:36:ED
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2305 errors:0 dropped:6 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:675 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:402213 (392.7 KiB)  TX bytes:67816 (66.2 KiB)
          Interrupt:5

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:E3:27:86:36:EF
          inet6 addr: fe80::62e3:27ff:fe86:36ef/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3761 errors:0 dropped:192 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:376 errors:298 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:309110 (301.8 KiB)  TX bytes:122376 (119.5 KiB)
          Interrupt:4

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1728 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1728 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:146016 (142.5 KiB)  TX bytes:146016 (142.5 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:E3:27:86:36:EE
          inet6 addr: fe80::62e3:27ff:fe86:36ee/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18073 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15017 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1727284 (1.6 MiB)  TX bytes:1680411 (1.6 MiB)
```

Comment: там по инструкции в второй части заливают файлы по scp, где похоже и происходит установка web интерфейса. Этот шаг прошли?

Comment: да все сделал. кроме этих: /etc/init.d/uhttpd enable
/etc/init.d/uhttpd start 
таких файлов вообще нету в каталоге. Вообще как это может быть цвет горит, а интернета нету

Comment: У Вас нет сетевого подключения (что не удивительно). После кардинальной смены прошивки настройки потерялись.

Comment: Вот как теперь настроит ?( У меня дефолтные настройки были у tp-link. Инет оптиковолокновый. ip динамичный. И ещё когда напрямую подключаю кабель на комп без роутера инет работает.

Comment: 1. сначала стоит [читать про своё железо](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr740n), а уж потом пробовать. версий номер пять там присутствует аж три (если считать и версию 5.1), причём одна из них не обладает достаточным количеством памяти. если у вас такая, то рекомендую отказаться от использования *openwrt*. 2. попробуйте повторно сбросить настройки, выполнив команду `$ firstboot`.

Comment: 3. проект *openwrt* развивается, конечно, довольно медленно, но не до такой степени, чтобы стоило рисковать следовать инструкции трёхлетней давности, касающейся, к тому же, [другого железа](https://wiki.openwrt.org/ru/toh/tp-link/tl-wr741nd).

Comment: Слава Богу у меня v5.0 кажется. Под модема так написано. Именно v5.0, а не v5. firstboot не помогал. У меня динамический ип. Кажется надо настроит dhcp.